# Incremental backups (mariabackup) and dropped databases

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

I tried to search for this case everywhere but, couldn't find anything that answers this - probably weird - question: What happens to the incremental backups taken from a mariadb server using `mariabackup` if one of the databases is dropped?

Suppose you dropped one of the databases in a mariadb server, then you created an incremental backup afterwards, where the base full backup certainly includes the dropped database, does applying the incremental backup when preparing to restore include that removal? or that dropped database will still be present in the fully prepared backup?

PS: I realize that mariabackup uses InnoDB LSN to backup the changes / diffs only but, do those diffs include the removal of a table or a database?

My guess is that when preparing the incremental backup over the base, it would remove the tables and / or databases which are missing from the latest delta backups but, I might be wrong so, that's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after trying out the scenario I've found out that the dropped databases do exist in the full integral backup but, their tables are removed.

So, I think that a database structure changes are also included in the incremental backup e.g. modifications in table columns, foreign keys, indices, table creation and dropping etc.. are all tracked but, dropping the database itself is NOT tracked however, a dropped database will have all its tables missing from the result backup of integrating all incremental backups to the base one.